# What are the best WordPress plugins to speed up your site loading?

Tags: wordpress, compression

Any JavaScript or CSS compression plugins you can recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/). It can compress and minify everything, as well as caching pages and posts.

Comment: Thanks! There are so many, I just wanted a second opinion.

Comment: you're welcome. This one's widely used, myself included, well-supported, compatible with vast number of plugins. If nobody else answers, can you click on the big 'check' mark to accept my answer? thanks.

Comment: I find W3 Total Cache works really well with [JCH Optimize](https://www.jch-optimize.net) plugin. Both of these plugin together can speed up your wordpress site dramatically as jch does other stuffs like minimizing http request and so on.